# Lucene Search for SiteCore get Field content from result

Tags: search, lucene, sitecore

Hy. I have run into a small problem. I am using Lucene Search and I am trying to get the content from a field in the returned result. I have got so far until the ID's of the field. Right now i get the field's ID' like that.

```
foreach (var i in hit.Template.InnerItem.InnerData.Fields)
        {
            hitParagraph = hitParagraph + i.ToString();
        }
```

This gives me the ID's of the field inside that template like this

[{25BED78C-4957-4165-998A-CA1B52F67497}, 20130307T051813][{5DD74568-4D4B-44C1-B513-0AF5F4CDA34F}, vh\branea1][{8CDC337E-A112-42FB-BBB4-4143751E123F}, 51885b42-bf8b-4f26-8259-125d352457f3][{D9CF14B1-FA16-4BA6-9288-E8A174D4D522}, .....

Please some help. 
Thank You

Comment: Can you clarify what you are trying to accomplish, and provide some of the preceding code here? What type of object is "hit"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand from your code, the `hit` is a Sitecore `Item` class instance. To get all the fields from it, use:

```
hit.Fields.ReadAll();
foreach (Field field in hit.Fields)
{
    hitParagraph = hitParagraph + field.Key + ": " + item[field.Key] + "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure what you're after. If it's the content of a specific field, you could just use `hit["fieldname"]` (assuming hit is a Sitecore item). Or `hit.Template.InnerItem["fieldname"]` would work, I think.

I think you don't need the InnerData bit - if you want a foreach loop I think you could do it like so:

```
foreach (Field i in hit.Template.InnerItem.Fields)
{
    hitParagraph += i.Value.ToString();
}
```